# How to define a Method with no return in C#

Tags: c#

I'm a beginner in C#.
I want to define a Method that has an input. And the input will be shown in an alert box with this Method.
In other words, the duty of this method is receiving a variable.
Every where that I call this method, the message will be alerted.
I want to know how to define and How to call.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Basic informational resources on the internet will go a long way and people like to see "prior effort". This was suggested in a comment below: [Beginner's Guide to C#](http://www.codepedia.com/1/BeginnersGuideToCSharp) (but this is not an exclusive guide/tutorial ... and hence reason for all the down-votes).

Comment: If someone is a beginner we should help him not disappointing him

Comment: Just because a question is simple does not mean it does not need an answer.  While I am not a new coder I am new to C# so I appreciated having this question appear on the first page of google results.  It answered my question in less than 10 seconds.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

your return type should be "void"

for example:

```
public void showMsg(string text)
{
    MessageBox.Show(text);
}
```

you would call your method like this:

```
showMsg("I can has alert?");
```

Comment: @Iman Hejazi: I added a sample

Comment: @Iman Hejazi, try checking out http://www.codepedia.com/1/BeginnersGuideToCSharp it goes over all these kind of basics

Comment: @Neil N , In your example, whenever the method showMsg is called, the Messagebox shows only "text", you should have written like this MessageBox.Show(text);

Comment: @Coder323: you are correct sir, this is what happens when you don't even compile!

Answer (score 6):

All you have to do is declare the return type as void:

```
public void MyMethod(string input)
{
    MessageBox.Show(input);
}
```